# Download a file using JQuery, ajax and c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have tried many articles on net for downloading a text file using JQuery, Ajax and C#. Most of them says you cannot download file using ajax.

Here is my JQuery-Ajax code

```
    $(document).on("click", "#imgDownload", function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/members/DownloadSelectedFile?SelectedUserName=" + $("#AllowedFriends").find(":selected").text() + "&SelectedFileName=" + $(this).siblings("span").eq(0).text(),
            success: function () {
                alert("Khushi");
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is my C# code

```
public void DownloadSelectedFile(string SelectedUserName, string SelectedFileName)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "Filename=" + SelectedFileName + ".txt");
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Users/" + SelectedUserName + "/" + (string)Session["LoggedInUserName"] + "/" + SelectedFileName + ".txt"));
            Response.End();
        }
```

So, what are the changes that I need to make to be able to download a text file.

Comment: See https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an IFrame to your document, either runat=server or not.... The following example requires you keep it client

```
<iframe id="myDownloaderFrame" style="display:none;" ></iframe>


$(document).on("click", "#imgDownload", function (event) {
    $("#myDownloaderFrame").attr("src","/members/DownloadSelectedFile?SelectedUserName=" + $("#AllowedFriends").find(":selected").text() + "&SelectedFileName=" + $(this).siblings("span").eq(0).text());

});
```

Comment: Thanks fahadash, This solves my problem. But can you explain me `what is iFrame?`

Comment: [IFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) allows you to have web-page inside a web-page as an control. Much like PIP feature on your latest TV.... This is going to be the only way you can do frames in HTML5, in earlier HTML versions you could use <frameset> too.

Comment: I remember using <frameset>. I used it to divide the page in many parts while I was learning HTML. Thanks for explanation.